# Get only those rows where column a has as many duplicate entries, as many there is distinctive values in column b

Tags: mysql, sql

My current query:

```
select users.id as user_id, opportunities.id as op_id, opportunities.title, certificates.id as cert_id from opportunities
join opportunity_certificates on opportunities.id=opportunity_certificates.opportunity_id
join certificates on opportunity_certificates.certificate_id=certificates.id
join user_certificates on certificates.id=user_certificates.certificate_id
join users on user_certificates.user_id=users.id
where opportunity_certificates.is_required = 1 and
opportunities.id = 1
```

This produces the table on the picture below.
cert_id column can have values from 1 to 7, depends on the `opportunities.id`. In the table below, I want the query to return only the rows which have the same user_id but different cert_id, 1 and 2.

If the table had 3 different cert_id, I would want it to return only the rows which have same user_id but different cert_id, 1,2 and 3.

when the cert_id has only one value, query should return all the records with that one value in cert_id. Basically, it should show all users who have all required certificates.

The query has to be in the current format. I experimented with

```
group by users.id
  having count(*) >
```

but I don't know how to make that comparison dynamic, relative to the count of distinctive values in the `cert_id` column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compare counts with a `having` condition.

```
select u.id as user_id --, o.id as op_id, o.title
from opportunities o
join opportunity_certificates oc on o.id=oc.opportunity_id
join certificates c on oc.certificate_id=c.id
join user_certificates uc on c.id=uc.certificate_id
join users u on uc.user_id=u.id
where oc.is_required = 1 and o.id = 1
group by u.id --,o.id,o.title
having count(distinct c.id)=(select count(distinct id) from certificates)
```

Comment: `having count(distinct certificates.id)=2` does work for the table in question but your code does not unfortunately. It returns 75 rows, all users who have certificate 1 OR certificate 2

Comment: title does not matter though. I need only user_id's of all users who have all the certificates in the cert_id column

Comment: And cert_id can have either 1 or more distinct values. Thank you for helping though. I sat thinking how to do this whole bloody day :)

Comment: `having count(distinct c.id) = (select count(distinct c.id))` this should be 1=1 or 2=2 or 4=4 but for some reason it doesn't work and returns 75 results of all users who have certificate 1 OR certificate 2

Comment: try the edited version..commented out columns not needed.

Comment: Nah, this last line is not returning 2... Now I get 0 results and I should be getting 3

Answer (score 0):

Useful?

```
with data as (
    select users.id as user_id, o.title, c.id as cert_id
    from opportunities o
        inner join opportunity_certificates oc on oc.opportunity_id = o.id
        inner join certificates c on c.id = oc.certificate_id
        inner join user_certificates uc on uc.certificate_id = c.id
        inner join users u on u.id = uc.user_id
    where oc.is_required = 1 and o.id = 1
)
select user_id, min(title) as title, max(cert_id) as num_certs
from data
group by user_id
having count(cert_id) = (select max(cert_id) from data);
```

I'm assuming that `cert_id` values start and 1 and run sequentially. You could also use `count(distinct ...)` in the `having` clause but it guess it's debatable which ones expresses you intent more clearly.

If your version of MySQL doesn't support CTEs then you should be able to just drop that whole subquery into the `having` clause as well.

```
select u.id as user_id, min(o.title) as title, max(c.cert_id) as num_certs
from opportunities o
    inner join opportunity_certificates oc on oc.opportunity_id = o.id
    inner join certificates c on c.id = oc.certificate_id
    inner join user_certificates uc on uc.certificate_id = c.id
    inner join users u on u.id = uc.user_id
where oc.is_required = 1 and o.id = 1
group by u.id
having count(c.cert_id) = (
    select max(c.cert_id)
    from opportunities o
        inner join opportunity_certificates oc on oc.opportunity_id = o.id
        inner join certificates c on c.id = oc.certificate_id
        inner join user_certificates uc on uc.certificate_id = c.id
        inner join users u on u.id = uc.user_id
    where oc.is_required = 1 and o.id = 1
);
```

Here's another one that might work if you have window functions available. (It might work with Laravel better?):

```
select *
from (
    select users.id as user_id, o.title,
        count(distinct c.id) over (partition by u.id) as user_certs,
        max(c.id) over () as total_certs
    from opportunities o
        inner join opportunity_certificates oc on oc.opportunity_id = o.id
        inner join certificates c on c.id = oc.certificate_id
        inner join user_certificates uc on uc.certificate_id = c.id
        inner join users u on u.id = uc.user_id
    where oc.is_required = 1 and o.id = 1
) t
where user_certs = total_certs;
```

Comment: ```select u.id, o.id, o.title, c.id
from opportunities o
join opportunity_certificates oc on o.id=oc.opportunity_id
join certificates c on oc.certificate_id=c.id
join user_certificates uc on c.id=uc.certificate_id
join users u on uc.user_id=u.id
where oc.is_required = 1 and o.id = 1
group by u.id
having count(distinct c.id) = 2```

This one gets me the right result but that last line where I compare the count to "2" is something that has to be changed. I can't drop that whole query to `having` clause as this sql statement will be converted to Laravels $opportunity->select([])...

Comment: @Varin I don't know anything about Laravel restrictions. Perhaps you have to run it in two steps and parameterize that part. That kind of limitation also should be added to the question.

Comment: Or perhaps you just use `raw`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the Laravel but either way, all those tables are related, why is it such a problem to basically pull all users who have all required certificates with a simpler query?

Comment: Well because you're wanting to do comparison over a summary value and without some of the more recent additions to SQL those queries have always been more complicated to write. MySQL has been behind for quite a few years.